# Oracle Active Sessions making my web application irresponsive - requires stopping golden gate replication to solve the problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

Infrastructure:
I have deployed oracle database at 5 remote locations and a web application that is deployed on 4 sites which accesses those oracle database, each working independently. However database on each site are synchronized with other database sites through Oracle Golden Gate.

Problem: At some point in time database active session on 1 of the site keep on increasing making the web application irresponsive (all database operations are halted) unless I stop golden gate replication on that particular site.

I tried to assess SQL queries that are taking too long in database sessions, but those seems normal queries which work fine when sessions are low.

Am I missing any golden gate configuration or there is any other area to probe?

Comment: Or what - make sure when you open a connection in the web application that you also close it.

Comment: yup, that's taken care of.